# MouseEventArgs from a subroutine

Tags: vb.net, charts, mouseevent, paint

I have a chart in Visual Studio 2013 and I can draw a line on it using the MouseventArgs handler. No worries.

But.... how can you have a separate subroutine that then uses the mouse events to draw a line. What I am need is if I hit a button, draw a line, if I did not hit the button use the regular mouseventargs.

So the button needs to start this:

```
enter code herePrivate Sub Chart1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles chD.MouseDown
    FirstPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
    TempPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles chD.MouseMove
    If Not FirstPoint = Nothing Then
        Dim g As Graphics = chD.CreateGraphics
        Dim ErasePen As Pen = New Pen(Me.BackColor)
        g.DrawLine(ErasePen, FirstPoint, TempPoint)
        TempPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Me.Refresh()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles chD.MouseUp

    Dim Line As New LineEndPoints With {.StartPoint = FirstPoint, .endPont = New Point(e.X, e.Y)}
    LinesList.Add(Line)
    FirstPoint = Nothing
    Me.Refresh()

End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles chD.Paint

    For Each line As LineEndPoints In LinesList
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, line.StartPoint, line.endPont)
    Next
    If Not FirstPoint = Nothing Then
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, FirstPoint, TempPoint)
    End If

End Sub`
```

`
Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You don't create a `MouseEventArgs` yourself. It is provided to you by certain events. It's an object like any other, so you can pass it to another method like you would any other object, e.g. and `Integer`, `String` or `DataTable`. If you want to use the data contained in the `MouseEventArgs` when a event is raised then you need to use fields, i.e. member variables, to store the data in between. You set one or more fields in the `MouseMove` event handler and then get the values in the other event handler. No magic to it at all.

Comment: Yet another CreateGraphics() victim.  You must use the Chart.PostPaint event instead.

Comment: Okay Hans, I appreciate your comment, but if you want to offer advice, offer the help. I have searched high and low for the Paint event and do not see how that changes anything I have done above.